# lodash - filter function using an array of filters objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I wonder how I could use `lodash` to filter some objects using an array of filters options.

So far, I have a function that can use the array of filters option but I can't manage to take the `LOGICAL` operator (AND, OR) into consideration.

**Edit:**

we find those objects which match every `LOGICAL` : `AND` condition or any `LOGICAL` : `OR` condition

**See this demo:**

```
var toFilter = [
    {"foo" : 1, "bar": 0}, 
    {"foo" : 1, "bar": 0}, 
    {"foo" : 2, "bar": null}
];

var filters = [
    {"KEY": "foo", "VALUE": 1, "EQUALITY": "EQUAL", "LOGICAL": "OR"}, 
    {"KEY": "bar", "VALUE": 0, "EQUALITY": "NOT_EQUAL", "LOGICAL": "AND"}
];

//the function should be equivalent to this one:
_.filter(toFilter, function(obj) { return obj.foo == 1 || obj.bar != 0 });

//this function does not take the LOGICAL operator ("AND" and "OR") in consideration
_.uniq(_.flatMap(filters, function(filter) {
     return _.filter(toFilter, function(obj) {
        if (filter.EQUALITY == "EQUAL") {
            return obj[filter.KEY] == filter.VALUE;
        } else {
            return obj[filter.KEY] != filter.VALUE;
        }
     });
}));
```

This is a very simple example, but the list of filters could be a lot larger.

Comment: What do your logical operators apply to?  They are boolean operators, but they seem to be applied to single values (e.g. `obj['foo'] === 1  AND ???`.)

Comment: all filtered objects must return `true` to every filter that have the `LOGICAL` set to `"AND"` except if they return `true` to a filter that have the `LOGICAL` set to `"OR"`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not making much sense out of that.  Perhaps some suggested output would help.  In the end, do you want a list of filters that match your objects or a list of objects that match your filters?

Comment: Hummm... the `"AND"` are filters that work altogether. The object must pass all those filters, if not it must pass one of the `"OR"` filters. Else, the object is not in the result.

Comment: So you can't represent `cond1 AND (cond2 OR cond3)`?

Comment: Could we phrase it as: "we find those objects which match every `AND` condition or any `OR` condition?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).  This might do what you need.  If there are actual duplicates you need to remove, then lodash's `uniq` could be added easily enough.

```js
const conditions = {
  'EQUAL': (a, b) => a === b,
  'NOT_EQUAL': (a, b) => a !== b,
}

const check = (objs, filters) => objs.filter(obj => {
  const ands = filters.filter(filter => filter.LOGICAL === 'AND')
  const ors = filters.filter(filter => filter.LOGICAL === 'OR')
  return ors.some(
    filter => conditions[filter.EQUALITY](obj[filter.KEY], filter.VALUE)  
  ) || (ands.length && ands.every(
    filter => conditions[filter.EQUALITY](obj[filter.KEY], filter.VALUE)  
  ))
})


const toFilter = [
  {foo : 1, bar: 0,    id: 'a'}, 
  {foo : 1, bar: 0,    id: 'b'}, 
  {foo : 2, bar: null, id: 'c'},
  {foo : 2, bar: 0,    id: 'd'}, 
];

const filters = [
  {KEY: "foo", VALUE: 1, EQUALITY: "EQUAL",     LOGICAL: "OR"}, 
  {KEY: "bar", VALUE: 0, EQUALITY: "NOT_EQUAL", LOGICAL: "AND"}
];

console.log(check(toFilter, filters))  //=> ids a, b and c
```

Note that this design makes it easy to add new conditions. For instance:

```
  'GREATER_THAN': (a, b) => a > b
```

If this is for the web, and you don't have a build process, I would recommend storing the conditions in a local closure for the function, with something like this (untested):

```
const check = (() => {
  const conditions = {
    'EQUAL': (a, b) => a === b,
    'NOT_EQUAL': (a, b) => a !== b,
  }

  return (objs, filters) => (objs, filters) => objs.filter(obj => {
    const ands = filters.filter(filter => filter.LOGICAL === 'AND')
    const ors = filters.filter(filter => filter.LOGICAL === 'OR')
    return ors.some(
      filter => conditions[filter.EQUALITY](obj[filter.KEY], filter.VALUE)  
    ) || (ands.length && ands.every(
      filter => conditions[filter.EQUALITY](obj[filter.KEY], filter.VALUE)  
    ))
  })
})()
```

Answer (score 3):

This will be my approach to solve the problem:

```js
var toFilter = [{ foo: 1, bar: 0 }, { foo: 1, bar: 0 }, { foo: 2, bar: null }];

var filters = [
  { KEY: 'foo', VALUE: 1, EQUALITY: 'EQUAL', LOGICAL: 'OR' },
  { KEY: 'bar', VALUE: 0, EQUALITY: 'NOT_EQUAL', LOGICAL: 'AND' }
];

var orFilters = _.filter(filters, ['LOGICAL', 'OR']);
var andFilters = _.filter(filters, ['LOGICAL', 'AND']);

var result = _.filter(toFilter, evalFilters);

function evalFilters(obj) {
  var curriedEquality = equality(obj);
  return (
    _.some(orFilters, curriedEquality) ||
    (andFilters.length && _.every(andFilters, curriedEquality))
  );
}

function equality(obj) {
  return function(filter) {
    return filter.EQUALITY === 'EQUAL'
      ? obj[filter.KEY] === filter.VALUE
      : obj[filter.KEY] !== filter.VALUE;
  };
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The first step is to separate the `OR` filters and the `AND` filters in two different arrays.

Then I would iterate over the elements to be filtered, I would make a curried function `equality` which will receive the element to be evaluated and returns a function which contains the equality comparison.

Then I would use `_.some` to check if the element evals to true in at least one `OR` filter if not, I would use `_.every` to verify if the element evals to true in all the `AND` filters.

**Obs:** Is necessary to verify if the `andFilters` array is not empty, because `_.every` and also `Array.prototype.every` will return `true` if it's the case.

Hope this explanation helps!

Comment: Can you make this into a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753)?

Comment: good point about the AND filters!  That should be fixed in my solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it a snippet, thanks for the feedback